# Helm unable to retrieve search results

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have stable repo configured

```
▶ helm repo list
NAME        URL
stable      https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com
```

and I know I can perform

```
helm install stable/jenkins
```

Then why isn’t the following command retrieving any results?

```
▶ helm search repo stable/jenkins
No results found
~
▶ helm search repo jenkins
No results found
```

Using

```
▶ helm version --tls
Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.9.1", GitCommit:"20adb27c7c5868466912eebdf6664e7390ebe710", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.16.8", GitCommit:"145206680c1d5c28e3fcf30d6f596f0ba84fcb47", GitTreeState:"clean"}
```

**edit**: even after an update

```
▶ helm repo update
Hang tight while we grab the latest from your chart repositories...
...Successfully got an update from the "flagger" chart repository
...Successfully got an update from the "incubator" chart repository
...Successfully got an update from the "stakater" chart repository
...Successfully got an update from the "stable" chart repository
...Successfully got an update from the "bitnami" chart repository
Update Complete. ⎈ Happy Helming!⎈

~/                                                                                                                                                                                                                     40m
▶ helm search repo stable/jenkins
No results found
```

I even tried to `remove` and `add` back again the `stable` repo; same result.

Comment: Try `helm search stable/jenkins` - this is helm v2 syntax. What you are using is helm3 syntax and its not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running `helm search repo stable/jenkins` and this is helm 3 syntax.

Have a look at this help for **helm3**:

```
$ helm search --help

Search provides the ability to search for Helm charts in the various places
they can be stored including the Helm Hub and repositories you have added. Use
search subcommands to search different locations for charts.

Usage:
  helm search [command]

Available Commands:
  hub         search for charts in the Helm Hub or an instance of Monocular
  repo        search repositories for a keyword in charts
```

But in you question you wrote:

> helm version --tls 
> Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"**v2.9.1** ...

This means that you are using **helm 2**. Now lets have a look at **helm 2** help command:

```
$ helm search --help
...
To look for charts with a particular name (such as stable/mysql), try
searching using vertical tabs (\v). Vertical tabs are used as the delimiter
between search fields. For example:

    helm search --regexp '\vstable/mysql\v'

To search for charts using common keywords (such as "database" or
"key-value store"), use
    helm search database
or
    helm search key-value store

Usage:
  helm search [keyword] [flags]
```

**TLDR:** Use:

```
helm search stable/jenkins
```

Let me know if you have any further questions. I'd be happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating your repositories:

```sh
$ helm repo add stable https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com

$ helm repo update
Hang tight while we grab the latest from your chart repositories...
...Successfully got an update from the "stable" chart repository
Update Complete. ⎈ Happy Helming!⎈ 

$ helm search repo stable/jenkins
NAME            CHART VERSION   APP VERSION DESCRIPTION                                       
stable/jenkins  2.1.0           lts         Open source continuous integration server. It s...
```

Comment: @pkaramol, then maybe helm version issue, try upgrading to helm 3.